# Run javascript on django login and logout events

Tags: javascript, python, django, authentication

Is it possible to execute JavaScript (in template) just after successful login event or just after a successful logout event. If yes, How?

I don't want to asscociate this with login button click or logout button click on JS level because

- Clicking the button is not a guarantee for successful login/logout event
- I have a lot of login and logout buttons, many templates and partials so looking for a centralized solution

By the way i am also using python-social-auth.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd approach it.

1. Make a view which has a template which contains the JS you want to execute on login (it could even be a basically blank page which redirects to somewhere else, or a template which extends another template... there are a myriad of ways to be DRY here, I think).
2. Set `SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`, `SOCIAL_AUTH_NEW_USER_REDIRECT_URL`, and/or `SOCIAL_AUTH_NEW_ASSOCIATION_REDIRECT_URL` (whichever of those you decide to use in step 3) in your `settings.py`.
3. Make an entry in your `urls.py` which makes that view accessible to either `SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` (or both `SOCIAL_AUTH_NEW_USER_REDIRECT_URL` and `SOCIAL_AUTH_NEW_ASSOCIATION_REDIRECT_URL`, if you only want it to execute for new users of your site).

I'm getting those settings variables from the [django-social-auth docs](http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#urls-options).